# Is “Was” needed in the sentence “The woman, who was had married John Lennon has been blamed for pulling the group apart.”

Tags: errors

I found the following paragraph in the article with the caption, "That Settles It: Yoko Ono Did Not Break Up Beatles” in Entertainment section of October 30 Time magazine:

> The Japanese artist and musician, who *was had married* John Lennon
>   shortly before the Beatles disbanded, has long been blamed for pulling
>   the group apart. But, according to a preview of the Frost interview
>   that appeared in The Guardian, McCartney dispels that notion. “[Ono]
>   certainly didn’t break the group up, the group was breaking up,” he is
>   quoted as saying.

I felt somewhat harsh on my ear with the expression- *“was had”* in the line “The Japanese artist and musician, who *was had* married John Lennon shortly before the Beatles disbanded, has long been blamed for pulling the group apart.”

Are both “was / had" necessary before 'married' in this sentence? Why is it? Can’t we say simply “The Japanese artist and musician, who had married John Lennon shortly before the Beatles disbanded,”

Comment: This is what I would call a "word-processor error": some writer or editor had written something like "The Japanese artist and musician, who married John Lennon shortly before ..." — and then decided to write "was married to" and changed it to "had married" or something and took out the "to" but forgot to remove the "was" from the sentence. It is an error, plain and simple.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi- Good catch.  Maybe they should hire you as their copy editor.

Comment: What @Robusto said. It looks exactly like the kind of error writers make with word-processors today, that they'd have been less likely to make in the days of pen and paper.

Comment: Why on earth do ***two*** people want to re-open this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence "The Japanese artist and musician, who ***was had*** married John Lennon shortly before the Beatles disbanded, has long been blamed for pulling the group apart", having ***was had*** makes it ungrammatical. It has to be one of the following to be grammatical idiomatic English:

> ..., who ***was*** married ***to*** John Lennon...
>   ..., who ***had*** married John Lennon...
>   or
>   ..., ***who married*** John Lennon...

This is probably an example of spell-checker copy-editing.

Comment: Not sure about your first option; it suggests she had stopped being married to him by the time they split up.  I think your third option is by far the best.  But have a +1.

Comment: This is typical AmE. However, I agree with your analysis. I too think the third one is best, but I'm sure that not all native speakers will agree on that.

Comment: I don't understand how how "spell-checker copy-editing" could cause such an error. It seems far more likely to me the original writer started with either *was* or *had*, but had second thoughts and switched to the other. And simply failed to correctly erase the first choice for some reason (having *third* thoughts, maybe, and unable to decide which to delete! :)

Comment: A spell checker would not underline either word, but a grammar checker would. I can turn off the grammar checker in MS Word. I can also turn off the spell checker. In any case, the piece wasn't properly copy-edited by the writer or the copy editor. If all they use is the spell checker, they won't catch such errors, which is why I always have both the spell checker and the grammar checker on. I frequently hallucinate when editing and think I've erased that wrong first choice. The grammar checker usually brings me back to reality.